# Weapon Focus Unarmed Strike?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Is it possible to apply the weapon focus feat line to unarmed strikes?

That is to say, any or all of the following:

1. Weapon Focus
2. Weapon Specialization
3. Greater Weapon Focus
4. Greater Weapon Specialization

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you [read the feats](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsFtb.html), they all explicitly say that you can!  Each contains the following line:

> You can also choose unarmed strike or grapple as your weapon for purposes of this feat.

So your specific question is easy.  A more general question is if that line is *necessary* -- and I'd say it isn't.  The rules consistently treat unarmed strike as just another type of weapon:

- It's listed in the table of weapons as a simple unarmed weapon, and gets a description along with the rest of them.  So if you're proficient with all simple weapons, you're proficient with unarmed strike.  (That's necessary for the feats to apply, of course.)
- The rules say in several places that it is treated as a light weapon, and use *Weapon Finesse* as an example.
- There are many places where the rules specify that particular aspects of the rules apply to unarmed strikes as if they were regular weapons -- you could consider that proof that they aren't *in general*, but that simply isn't the way D&D 3.5 was written.

So any feats that can apply to a weapon should be applicable to unarmed strike.

Answer (score 0):

## You can take Weapon Focus et al. in Natural Weapons

So the admittedly convoluted status of the Unarmed Strike is unimportant: even if you do call it a natural weapon, it’s still eligible for Weapon Focus.

The Unarmed Strike is generally treated as a natural weapon for the purposes of spell effects and feats (if you are a Monk, you *also* get to treat it like a manufactured weapon for those purposes), but it generally follows the rules of a manufactured weapon (e.g. it gets iteratives, cannot be combined with other manufactured weapons the way natural weapons usually can).

Thus, to answer starwed’s pondering, **no**, Weapon Focus need not specify unarmed strikes specifically as an option.